# Selectively hide links based on the previous class name

Tags: javascript, dom

First of all, I would like to ask you not to refer me to jQuery. I do not use jQuery, neither I would like to use it in this case.

That being said, let's see if I can describe my goal. I have a list of links as follows:

```
<a href="#" class="title">1ST TITLE</a>
<a href="#">Item 1</a>
<a href="#">Item 2</a>
... more items ...
<a href="#" class="title">2ND TITLE</a>
<a href="#">Item 1</a>
<a href="#">Item 2</a>
... more items ...
<a href="#" class="title">3RD TITLE</a>
<a href="#">Item 1</a>
<a href="#">Item 2</a>
... more items ...
```

and so on ( the total list is 77 links, including the title ones )

now, i hide all the NOT 'title' links like so:

```
var sideMenu = getElementsByClassName(document, 'sm');
var links = sideMenu[0].getElementsByTagName('a');
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (!hasClass(links[i], 'title')) {
        links[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

*`getElementsByClassName` and `hasClass` are function I've written for this.*

Up to here, everything works perfectly.

Now, what I would like to do, is, in case one of the `title` links has also an `active` class, then I dont want to hide the links that come after it.

For example, if the `2ND TITLE` had an `active` class, then I would like to show all following links of `2ND TITLE`, but still hide the `1ST TITLE` and `3RD TITLE` links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When iterating, keep track of whether the current link is beneath an active one: http://jsfiddle.net/8bwyU/1/.

```
function hasClass(elem, someClass) { // don't know your implementation...
    return elem.className.indexOf(someClass) !== -1;
}

var sideMenu = document.body.getElementsByClassName('sm'),
    links = sideMenu[0].getElementsByTagName('a'),
    currentIsActive = false;

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (!hasClass(links[i], 'title')) { // not a title link
       if(!currentIsActive) { // only hide if not under an active title link
           links[i].style.display = 'none';
       }
    } else { // a title link
        currentIsActive = hasClass(links[i], "active");
        // update whether current is active or not
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep a reference as to whether the last passed `title` link was active or not; if it was, then don't hide, otherwise do. Something like:

```
var sideMenu = getElementsByClassName(document, 'sm');
var links = sideMenu[0].getElementsByTagName('a');
var isActive = false;
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (hasClass(links[i], 'title') && hasClass(links[i], 'active'))
        isActive = true;
    if (hasClass(links[i], 'title') && !hasClass(links[i], 'active'))
        isActive = false;
    if (!hasClass(links[i], 'title') && !isActive) {
        links[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT** Providing there's only ever one title marked as active at any one time, you can achieve what you're looking for with pure CSS:

```
a.title ~ a:not(.title) { display: none; }
a.title.active ~ a:not(.title) { display: inline; }
a.title.active ~ a.title:not(.active) ~ a:not(.title) { display: none; }
```

Multiple active titles fails if the first and last are both active (other combinations work). Also, your mileage may vary depending on browser support :P